# Adding new files with resource(.resx) file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on the old application where many pages have resource file. Each file structure is(.aspx file, .aspx.vb file, and aspx.resx file).

Now I have added the new file by following MSDN resource.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hds5k93.aspx

In that file I can see the .aspx file, .aspx.vb file and the aspx.designer.vb file but I can't find the .aspx.resx file.

Can someone please help to create the resource file as existing files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resx files are located inside the `App_LocalResources` folder for page specific resource files or in the `App_GlobalResources` folder for globally accessible resource files.

If that folder does not exist you can add it to the project by right clicking on the project name and select `Add > Add ASP.NET Folder`.